# When using javascript onclick I'm getting a small link icon in IE, how do I remove this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

On the following website: http://fmcdevelopment.com/

Focus on the 3 slides in the middle with the 3 links beneath "99% Satisfaction, New, Studio10" and 2 blue arrow butons

In IE7, 8, 9, when you click the 3 links or the 2 arrows, a little icon pops up in top left of the container. If you keep clicking, more icons appear from left to right. When you click the icons you see that they are the onclick links from that javascript event.

What is this icon anyway?  In the other browsers these icons do not show up. I need these icons NOT to show up in IE7, 8, 9.

```
function imageSwap(action){
var state = $('#features-image').attr("src");

if (action == 'previous')
{
    switch(state)
        {
            case '/themes/default/images/HPSlide-NinetyNine-Percent-Satisfaction.jpg': 
                $("#features-image").ImageSwitch({Type:"FadeIn", NewImage:"/themes/default/images/HPSlide-Studio10.jpg"});
                $("#features-link").attr("href",'/our-features/studio10/');
                $('#features-text').html('<p><a href="#" onclick="imageSwap(\'next\');">99% Satisfaction</a> <a href="#" onclick="imageSwap(\'previous\');">New</a> <span class=\"features-selected\"><a href="/our-features/studio10/">Studio10</a></span></p>');
                break;
            case '/themes/default/images/HPSlide-New-Headquarters-Aerial.jpg':
                $("#features-image").ImageSwitch({Type:"FadeIn", NewImage:"/themes/default/images/HPSlide-NinetyNine-Percent-Satisfaction.jpg"});
                $("#features-link").attr("href",'/our-features/99-satisfaction/');
                $('#features-text').html('<p><span class=\"features-selected\"><a href="/our-features/99-satisfaction/">99% Satisfaction</a></span> <a href="#" onclick="imageSwap(\'next\');">New</a> <a href="#" onclick="imageSwap(\'previous\');">Studio10</a></p>');
                break;
            case '/themes/default/images/HPSlide-Studio10.jpg':
                $("#features-image").ImageSwitch({Type:"FadeIn", NewImage:"/themes/default/images/HPSlide-New-Headquarters-Aerial.jpg"});
                $("#features-link").attr("href",'/our-features/new-administration-building/');
                $('#features-text').html('<p><a href="#" onclick="imageSwap(\'previous\');">99% Satisfaction</a> <span class=\"features-selected\"><a href="/our-features/new-administration-building/">New</a></span> <a href="#" onclick="imageSwap(\'next\');">Studio10</a></p>');
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just added the above code to help bring clarity...

Comment: The correct answer was to add "style = "display:none;" to the style of GrpEffectImg to make IE happy

Answer (score 1):

That "icon" that is popping up is an image tag without a valid source attribute or valid height/width attributes.

It appears as though you have a `click` event handler on the links you describe in your question that adds an image to the page that is not functioning properly.

The most probable reason you only see the "icon" in Internet Explorer is because the other browsers don't show an "icon" when an image cannot be found unless you specify width and height attributes for the image.

**UPDATE**

You most likely have some JavaScript code that is creating these images and there is an error when doing so. Here is a sample image I copied from my developer tools:

```
<img class="GrpEffectImg" id="GrpEffectImg-[object Object]"/>
```

You probably need to specify a property of the object that you are adding to the ID of the image. Instead of:

```
var img = '<img class="GrpEffectImg" id="GrpEffectImg-' + someObject + '"/>';
```

Use:

```
var img = '<img class="GrpEffectImg" id="GrpEffectImg-' + someObject.someProperty + '"/>';
```

I cannot be sure what syntax to use with your object but the above example should demonstrate what to do.

Comment: @JohnParronHinson The code you posted does not add an image to the DOM, look for the place in your code that has the following string: `GrpEffectImg` because the images that are appearing have that class.

Comment: var c=function(){i.parent().append("<img class='GrpEffectImg' id='"+k.replace("#","")+"'/>");

Comment: there are 9 uses of this GrpEffectImg in the ImageSwitch.js file, 3 of which look similar to the one in the above comment.

Comment: @JohnParronHinson Apparently `k` is an object and the `.replace()` function is expecting a string. Maybe just before the code you posted, output the `k` object to see what it is: `console.log(k);var c=...`